# XCode Could not launch App, Operation not permitted

Tags: ios, xcode

When trying to run a project in a device, XCode isn't able to launch the application (even though it ends up correctly installed and I can run it manually by clicking on its icon).

A dialog is shown with the following contents:

**Could not launch “App name”
process launch failed: Operation not permitted**

I have encountered many launch problems over the times but they were solvable either by removing the derived data or making sure no strange file was being copied in the resources.

This time I have tried everything, even restarting the computer but the problem remains.

I am using a debug provision profile.

Has anyone had the same problem?

Answer (score 2):

Ok I finally figured out the problem. This problem happens when your product name contains a dot.

I was using "com.company" as the product (and target) name and switching it to "company" fixed the "operation not permitted" problem.